# Pillow's polygon scanline artifact

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm not really sure if it's a bug or that I'm doing something wrong, but when I try using ImageDraw.polygon, Pillow breaks and adds scanline marks out of nowhere [Scanlined Iceland](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbvI7.png)

I triple checked the path and it was correct, then I tried drawing the same path with ImageDraw.line and it worked fine, no extra lines or other artifact, which presumably means that I don't have weird vertices
[Normal Iceland](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpXRY.png)

```
img = Image.new("RGB", TARGETSIZE, (255,255,255))
img1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img) 
for p in paths:
    img1.polygon(p, fill = (0, 0, 0))
```

This happens only on some drawings, which I think means that the code working fine.
Pillow version: 9.1.0

Comment: Not sure how anyone can help you without a [mcve] of your minimal code and data.

Comment: More concretely, what's in your `paths`?

Comment: Are you sure your polygon is a [simple polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon)?